# Select all columns except specific (by name) in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
a b   c   d   e      
1 rr  dfv 5   0.1
9 t   rr1 222 0.44
7 sdf we  1   0.111
```

I want to select all columns except say d and e.
I know I can use subset for this: `subset(df, -c(d, e))`
Why can't I do `df[,-c(d,e)]`?

Please advise.

P.S @sotos and others:

x[,-c("b", "c")] Error in -c("b", "c") : invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: For some reason it didn't work, maybe it depends on the R version.

Comment: x[,-c("b", "c")]
Error in -c("b", "c") : 
  invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: @sotos please review again, what is wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong. It is just a duplicate. Go through the link and you will find the solution very easily. Also have in mind that questions about "What is wrong with my code" and "Why isn't my code working" are outside the scope of SO

Comment: I am following @AleksandrVoitov solution and it didn't work. Please provide me with the link, I don't see any link here. Sorry if it's duplicate didn't find the question before asking mine.

Comment: At the top of your question.

Comment: @Sotos I have checked the link you provided and still didn't answer my question why df[, -c("a","b")] won't work?
They use which and subset there but not what I am asking for.

Comment: Read my comment above about "Why isn't my code working". Of course in your case, It doesn't work simply because it is the wrong syntax.

Comment: @Sotos would you be so kind and tell me what is wrong please?

Comment: Simply wrong syntax. You can call it by name directly (i.e. `iris['Species']`) but to exclude a column the minus sign will not work. You need to specify it by calling the `names` (column names) of your data frame and excluding (via `!` and `%in%`) the ones you want to remove

Comment: R try to evaluate -c("a", "b")  which translate to do negative of string "a" and string "b". -ve of string doesn't make sense in usual R syntax. You can check this by typing -"a" in  the R prompt same error will happen.

Comment: Does not work unless you add "select" subset(df, select=c(-c(d,e)))